# How to remove orphaned app shortcut from search results windows 10

Tags: windows-10, anaconda

I became frustrated and deleted the install directory for [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html). Now, Anaconda Prompt still shows up in Windows Search (from the task bar).

How do I remove this orphaned shortcut?

Comment: Should be as simple as right clicking the shortcut and removing it from the start menu

Comment: Hmm. It's not in the Start Menu. I'm using the "Search" icon in the task bar. If you right click the orphaned item, this shows 'uninstall'. Click this and it takes you to the system's uninstall applications feature in Control Panel, and the application is no longer listed.

Comment: Sounds like you should reinstall the application and try uninstalling it again.